# Android: Hide JPEGs from Gallery App

Tags: android, image, file, permissions

Working on an Android app that downloads images in JPEG format internally and then displays them within the app.

The issue is that the default Gallery App, shows those images as it scans entire storage for JPEG or PNG files. That causes confusion w/ some users as they do not expect to see internal app images next to their family photos.

My initial thoughts are to rename the extension. But before that, does anyone know if perhaps a simpler way exists by using permissions?

Comment: Download them to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), not [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "it scans entire storage for JPEG or PNG files" -- no, it scans external storage and, usually, [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: Thanks, you are right that would work, but I have a requirement to keep files on external storage. I also think, saving to internal would bloat the app size in the app manager if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Giving them a unique file extension that only your app looks for would be simplest.